# Is there a way to "standardise" column names from json file?

Tags: json, ajax, datatable

I have a json file generated by 3 queries that i want to display in a datatable.
In all 3 the queries, the information is the same but the table column has different names:

- 1st column: num_paiements, num_depot and num_virement (those are row id)
- 2nd column: date_paiement, date_depot and date_virement
- 3rd column: not a problem since its the same name

The result: the values int the 2 first columns will only show for 1 of the 3, depending on i enter in the code below.
Is there a way i could just say something like data: [0] and data: [1] for the first 2 columns?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#operations').DataTable( {
      "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/statham.json",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "num_paiements" },
            { "data": "date_paiement" },
            { "data": "montant" }
        ]

    } );
} );
```

Comment: You should set unique keys for the "columns". Not data,data,data but instead num_paiements, date_paiement and montant. Where um_paiements, date_paiement and montant. is now the actual values should be.

Comment: You could also do like this: { "data": [value for "num_paiements" , value for date_paiement, value for montant] }. Then it would be accesible as you describe. data[0], data[1] etc.

Comment: btw. How is this PHP?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... Maybe i wasn't clear. This is wath I try to achieve:
        columns
            data: num_paiements or num_depot or num_viremen
            data: date_paiements or date_depot or date_virement,
            data: montant
   
PS: I added PHP because in my numerous searches, I had lots of posts related to other languages

Comment: I removed PHP because you are not asking about PHP :-)

Comment: You're basically saying you want this: "columns": [{ "data": ["num_paiements","date_paiement","montant"] }] but the values can change?

Comment: If I understood your issue correctly , you should not have to have the actual column-name in your json-file. It's the value that's important. You can have another key/value pair in your json that indicates which query it is so the server knows what to do with it?

Comment: No. The first column is for the ID (payment,virement or depot)
The second column is for the date (payment,virement or depot)
The third is the amount
Only the amount has the same name in MySQL table. Maybe the solution is to change the names in the database

Comment: Yes. :) The column anme does not mather. But for the first 2 columns, the value can come from 3 different db column from 3 tables.

Comment: An idea would  be to have aliases in your queries so the result of the queries will always have  the same column names. And those column names you use in your datatable/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I i understood your problem correctly (and how the dataTable jquery works) an idea would be to have aliases in your queries so the result of the queries will always have the same column names. And those column names you use in your datatable/data.

You have:

- **1st column**: num_paiements, num_depot and num_virement (those are row
  id)
- **2nd column**: date_paiement, date_depot and date_virement
- **3rd column**: not a problem since its the same name

Grab those results by doing something like this in your SQL-query:

```
 1st column: SELECT num_paiements as data1 FROM table1
                   OR
                   SELECT num_depot as data1 FROM table2
                   OR
                   SELECT num_virement as data1 FROM table3
                   
 2nd column: SELECT date_paiement as data2 FROM table1
                   OR
                   SELECT date_depot as data2 FROM table2
                   OR
                   SECT date_virement as data2 FROM table3

 3rd column: not a problem since its the same name
```

and then have your code something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#operations').DataTable( {
      "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/statham.json",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "data1" },
            { "data": "data2" },
            { "data": "montant" }
        ]

    } );
} );
```